# Embedded Vimeo (iframe) fullscreen not working in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, vimeo, vimeo-player

I'm trying to embed vimeo videos as iframes. I'm using the following code:

```
<iframe width="1140" height="570" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/553469759?autoplay=1&dnt=1" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

It works fine when I paste it in a codepen or try it in firefox. It doesn't work in chrome for me though. When I inspect the iframe's HTML, I can see that vimeo adds a class `no-fullscreen-support`, it also added these classes though:

- `js-player-fullscreen`
- `with-fullscreen`

Comment: Hello @caevv , did you find a solution ? 
Same problem here , but mine work on all browser except chrome ... 
Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't find a solution. I did not work on this anymore for a while. Last time I checked on it, I think the fullscreen was still not working. Even though having all the attributes present, according to the docs.

Answer (score 5):

Figured it out on my end.  It was due to the Permissions-Policy being set by Nginx in the header.  In my instance of Nginx, it was originally set to this:

`add_header Permissions-Policy "geolocation=(),midi=(),sync-xhr=(),microphone=(),camera=(),magnetometer=(),gyroscope=(),fullscreen=(self),payment=()";`

The culprit in this case was `fullscreen=(self)` -- it was telling Chrome that unless the code originated from the site, it shouldn't allow full screen.  As Vimeo's iframe is being loaded from player.vimeo.com, Chrome saw that as a third party and wouldn't allow it. Removing that from the Permissions-Policy so it looked like this:

`add_header Permissions-Policy "geolocation=(),midi=(),sync-xhr=(),microphone=(),camera=(),magnetometer=(),gyroscope=(),payment=()";`

Resolved the problem.  The button is showing fine now.

For those using Apache, it'd probably look like this:

`Header always set Permissions-Policy "geolocation=(),midi=(),sync-xhr=(),microphone=(),camera=(),magnetometer=(),gyroscope=(),fullscreen=(self),payment=()"`

The same principle applies, just remove `fullscreen=(self)`.

You might also see it mentioned as Feature Policy, same thing, it's just called Permissions Policy now.

You can learn more about Permissions Policy here: https://github.com/w3c/webappsec-permissions-policy/blob/main/permissions-policy-explainer.md

Answer (score 0):

### From [Vimeo Help Center](https://vimeo.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115015759768-Fullscreen-button-missing-from-the-player):

The fullscreen button will be hidden from the player in scenarios where fullscreen mode cannot be activated. Here are some common causes:

- First and foremost, check the Embed tab. Make sure the fullscreen button is toggled on under the Controls section
- The iframe embed code is missing the fullscreen attributes: "mozallowfullscreen,""webkitallowfullscreen," and "allowfullscreen." If you’re pasting your embed code into another application, make sure these values are being retained.
- The player iframe is contained within another iframe that is missing the fullscreen attributes. Browsers do not allow iframes to enter fullscreen if they are contained within other iframes without these fullscreen attributes. - Try inserting the player outside of the container iframe or adding "mozallowfullscreen," "webkitallowfullscreen," and "allowfullscreen" to the container iframe.
- The iframe is contained within a frame. Frame elements cannot enter fullscreen, and neither can any iframes inside of them. We recommend removing all frame tags from your page’s source code.

If you're not sure if the above cases apply, please contact us, and we’ll investigate further.  Be sure to include a link to the page where the video is embedded, so we can take a closer look at your page's source code.

Answer (score 0):

You should add these tags to the element:

```
webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31864157)